# What can it mean "why do you just not come?"

Tags: sentence

I got the sentence in the drama called "IT CROWD".

"why do you just not come" , I dont think that means "Why do you not come?, I  expected you to come"

that's more like in a situation that someone is about to go out with his friend but doesn't want to walk, the friend could say "what about just not coming, you wouldn't have to walk then"

Is it right ? I am a bit confused, please help me out with that

From Season 2 Episode 1 : http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=the-it-crowd&episode=s02e01

quoted text:

> Let's get a taxi.
>
> It's a ten minute walk.
>
> No.  I don't like walking.
>
> **Why do you just not come**, then you wouldn't have to walk anywhere?

Comment: Can you provide some more context? What was said before and after that sentence?

Answer (score 3):

The transcription on that page is not very accurate. It seems to have been transcribed by someone who doesn't know English (or punctuation and line-breaking) very well.

The line you quote is perhaps in some contexts grammatical, but it is ***very*** unusual, and in the context here, it makes no sense whatsoever.

What Jen (the character who speaks the line) actually says is:

> Why *don’t* you just not come?

In other words, she's asking (in her hopes to have a proper date) why her coworkers don't just stay at home and not come along to the theatre with her and Philip.

Unlike the sentence transcribed on the page you linked to, this is a perfectly grammatical, idiomatic, and normal thing to say in the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a colloquial way of saying "Why don't you just come", ie "Why don't you simply come?".

It's possible that it was said by accident, ie that the actor **meant to say** the more idiomatic *"Why don't you just come?"*, and garbled their line slightly, but the change was so slight that it wasn't deemed throwing away the whole take for.  Often in films and television, actors are given a certain degree of licence to express the sentiment of the script without having to stick to the exact words, in order to produce a more natural performance.